# How can I converte a jpeg image to BPG in flutter?

Tags: flutter, jpeg, bpg

I need to convert JPEG images to BPG in flutter. Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) is your best bet: it can read, write and convert between most common image file formats.  Unfortunately, I don't believe BPG is supported (yet). Q: is there any reason you absolutely *need* BPG (vs. jpeg, .png or others)?  NOTE: you can easily convert jpeg to bpg (and vice versa) in many different ways.  You just can't easily use bpg in Dart/Flutter.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4! I need BPG because it is the best image compress algorithm and it is used in the legacy app(Objective C and java).

Comment: It's not "best" if you can't easily use it on your target platform :)  STRONG SUGGESTION: Use jpg or png with Dart/Flutter; use an external app to convert to and from bpg as needed.   [Imagmagick](https://imagemagick.org/) might be a good option: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/

Comment: Thanks, Paul! you are absolutely right! It is not best if you cannot use but I still have to find a solution. You gave a good idea but I cant use an external app. Thanks anyway.